# Removing unwanted edge

Tags: modeling, vertices

noob here, i'm trying to clean up the surface edge as indicated on red circle, from reference the surface should be smooth and no line, i don't know why it happens.
i also screenshot the vertices (geometry is clean imo) but i guess because some of the area i use knife tool to clean up and the loop cut isn't goes through from top to bottom as shown in the image. any idea how to fix? Btw i have also applied subdev modifier as well. thanks in advance

[image]

[image]jINU.jpg

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots sorry having an error in pasteall, but heres the file on dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5ly4mrld549iei/20220622%20Glock.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an inner face, remove it:

[image]